# Input time datetime-local to 24 hr format

Tags: php, html

So as you can see in this picture [image: Date] The time in the bottom right corner is 13:53:00, and it's 08-09-2020. Here I was wondering if there is a way to permanent change the time to 24hr (HH:MM) format, instead of "HH:MM PM/AM"

`echo"<input style='width: 45%;' type = 'datetime-local' id = 'mt_start' name = 'mt_start' required>";`

Comment: Mention the date picker libaray you are using.

Comment: @Habib none, I guess – this is the default datepicker Chrome shows for `<input type='datetime-local'>`

Comment: Yes it's the default chrome datepicker